# Using two EntityManager for the same JPA Object

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-entitymanager

I have a main DB and a secondary backup DB.

For the read operations I would like to use the secondary DB to free up usage on the main one.

I can create the persistence units and two entityManagers for the database connections. I have the same JPA classes for both connections.

Is it possible the use the two entitymanagers together?

I tried the following:

```
Integer id= 23; 
CustomObj obj = getEntityManagerReadOnly().find(CustomObj .class, id);
obj .setAtt("test");
getEntityManager().merge(obj );
```

This approach gives me error. 
Is there any way to use two datasource with Hibernate for the same JPA class.

I know that with Toplink it is probably possible: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/toplink/solutions/usingmultipledbs.htm#TLADG188

Comment: are you using spring to manage transactions?

Comment: you mean, like detach an object from one EM and merge it into the other one? But you haven't detached anything

Comment: I am not allowed to use spring

Comment: No I don't want to detach that is the point.